# Tabcontrol does clear function clear the attached controls (forms?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have several forms added to the pages of the tab control via tabcontrol.tabpages.controls.add function. If I then call tabpages.clear(), does it automatically clear the forms (I.E: Properly close each and indivudual forms) as well or do I have to close the forms individually before clearing the tab pages?

Comment: It "clears" the form.  But doesn't dispose it, the form object will leak forever.  You *must* call Dispose().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HansPassant mentioned, the TabPages still exist.  You could add them back in if you wanted to.

In place of calling `.Clear()`, try disposing every TabPage:

```
while (tabControl1.TabPages.Count > 0) {
  tabControl1.TabPages[0].Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try implementing the IDisposable Interface in a custom page or control. Then you are sure everything is closed properly because you can do it yourself in the Dispose method.

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx